# Powershell: create directory using filenames without extension and move files to new directory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move files (a bunch of files in a subdirectory), create a subfolder if it doesn't exist and then move the files to the subfolder

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path H:\Movies -File
#  for each($file in $files){
$file = $files[0]
$filename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
$path= "H:\movies\" + $filename
if (!(test-path -Path $path )){ #always returns false?
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path  
}
Move-Item $file.FullName $path
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that:

```
$path = 'H:\Movies'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File

foreach ($file in $files){
   # Get filename without extension
   $filename = $file.BaseName

   # Build new folderpath
   $newFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $filename

   # Check if folder already exists
   if (-not(Test-Path -Path $newFolderPath)) {
       New-Item -Path $path -Name $filename -ItemType Directory
   }

   # Move file to new folder
   $destination = Join-Path -Path $newFolderPath -ChildPath $file.Name
   Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destination
}
```

Comment: Nice! You can omit `Test-Path` when using `New-Item` with parameter `-Force`. It creates new directory only if it doesn't already exists.

Comment: Just tried it, works! Thanks for the tip @zett42

Answer (score 0):

I have Tested the below code using foreach and working fine for me.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Test -File

foreach($file in $files){

 #Write-Output $file.Name
 $filename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
 Write-Output $filename
 $path= "E:\Test\" + $filename
 Write-Output $path
 if (!(test-path -Path $path )){ 
    Write-Output "Not Exists: $path"
    #New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path 
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
   }
 Move-Item $file.FullName $path

}
```

Comment: I hate it when it works for me solutions, yet doesn't work for ME.  The directories are created but the files are not moved.

Comment: I have spaces in the filenames could this be the problem?

Comment: @DavidJohnson Working fine for me though spaces in the filename.

Comment: creates the directories fine.. just doesn't move the files.. I tried replacing the spaces with .'s and also on an exfat volume.. tried with windows server 2016 in a vm same old .. directories made files not moved

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on powershell and used file2foldergui instead